# hint for solving an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How can i solve the following ODE?

$$y'' y^n + y^{n+1}=1$$

Where $y:=y(x)$ is a differentiable function of $x$ and $y^n := yy ...y$.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: One obvious solution is $y=1$ but since it's non-linear I don't see how that helps.

Comment: @Moo I suspect that if $y^{(n)}$ were intended then the first term would have been written $y^{(n+2)}$

Comment: for $n=2$, wolframalpha gives an answer that's half a page long. seems like   a hard problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transform

$$y''+y=y^{-n},$$

$$y'y''+yy'=y^{-n}y',$$
(provided $y'\ne0$), then integrate
$$y'^2+y^2=\frac2{1-n}y^{1-n}+C,$$

and a second time

$$\int\frac{dy}{\sqrt{\frac2{1-n}y^{1-n}+C-y^2}}=x+C'.$$

---

When $C=3$, there is a nearly human-looking antiderivative https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+1%2Fsqrt(3-y%5E2-2%2Fy)dy

[image]

Comment: Note, that this neglects the special solutions $y=1$ and $y=-1$ for odd $n$. See comment of @John-Wayland-Bales.

Comment: @Tobias: I focused on the "hard stuff". Special cases such as $n=-1, y'=0$ and the handling of the sign of the square root are not handled.

Comment: Then you should at least mention this in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The differential equation is reduced to  a variable sepearble problem as follows on dividing by $y^n$ if $y\neq0$ :$y''+y=y^{-n}\implies\frac{y''}{y^{-n}-y}=1,y^{-n}\neq y$, which is difficult to be integrated further. However, as Yves Daoust has pointed out it can be integrated once by multiplying the original equation by $y'$. Note, however, that $y=1$ trivially satisfies this equation and $y=-1$ satisfies it for odd $n$, which are the singular solutions to this equation.

Comment: There is no resolution method for a separable equation of the second order as there is for the first order.

Comment: @YvesDaoust so, should I delete the answer?

Comment: In this particular case, as there is no instance of $y'$, the equation is in a way "doubly separable" and can be integrated if you multiply by $y'$. So your answer is a little "short".